# Can't git pull a submodule when git clone of repo wasn't recursive

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a GitHub repository (call it `parent-repo`), which has as a submodule another GitHub repository (say, `child-repo`). If I clone the root repo without `--recurse-submodules`, I get an empty folder for the submodule; and if I then try to `git pull`, even with `--recurse-submodules`, the subfolder doesn't get filled up. What am I supposed to do? A `git clone`?

When I clone the root with `--recurse-submodules` the subrepo folder gets populated just fine.

Comment: Submodules will require additional steps. Have you reviewed this https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After cloning a repository without recursing the submodules, e.g. in OP's case after:

```
git clone  git@github.com:eyalroz/parent-repo.git
```

you then do:

```
cd parent-repo/
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

and this gets you the contents of `child-repo`.

<sub>Credit goes to @osowskit for pointing me in the right direction.</sub>